# accordian view for webparts

Tags: development, administration

is there an out of the box feature / other that will allow me to create a view to give an "accordion" effect to hide and show webparts?

example:

```
section1
    webpart 1
    webpart 2
    webpart 3

section 2
    webpart 1
    webpart 2
    webpart 3

section 3
    webpart 1
    webpart 2
    webpart 3
```

so, the webparts would be hidden until the 'section' is clicked

Any help will be appreciated?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing directly out of the box but you can do something similar to this:  http://pathtosharepoint.com/pages/easyTabs.aspx with the out of the box webparts.  This guy is just using some javascript and a content editor webpart that he prepackaged.  You could modify what he had and change it over to an accordian or something else.  I know jquery.ui has a nice accordian feature.